# iptables port redirect with Docker

Tags: iptables, docker

I have a web service running on port 8080, which is made available on port 80 through iptables like so:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.0/8 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This works, however attempting to reach `127.0.0.1:80` inside a Docker container fails. I assume this is because `lo` within the container is a separate device inside a network namespace. Thus I attempted to do the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 172.17.0.0/16 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

where `172.17.0.0/26` is the range assigned to the `docker0` bridge interface. Connections to `172.17.42.1:80` (the IP assigned to `docker0`) still fail inside the container.

There are no firewall rules other than the standard set created by Docker.

Why is this forwarding rule still failing?

Versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-36-generic)
- Docker 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I fixed this by using a slightly different range and inserting a PREROUTING rule before dockers.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -p tcp -d 172.16.0.0/16 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first rule redirects anything in the 127.0.0.0/8 network to the local webservice, instead of what you probably intentioned to be things directed at lo.

Assuming you lo interface has IP 127.0.0.1 (which it almost certainly does) try this instead:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```